# Active Buttons with Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In my navbar, I want my buttons to become active (shaded) when I click on them. Right now, I can only permanently make them active or non-active but don't know how to have it change once I click on them. I'm using the new Bootstrap (3.0).

For example:

**Non-Active**

```
<li><%= link_to "Contact", contact_path %></li>
```

**Active**

```
 <li class="active"><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>
```

I want it to be active/non-active depending on whether the current page is selected or not.

Answer (score 9):

Use JavaScript.

Example with jQuery:

```
$('ul li').click( function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qDdjE/)**

Or with more bootstrap:

**[Bootstrap 3 DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jdE2v/1/)**

Comment: thanks for the response. I'm a complete beginner, could you please explain where to implement this as well?

Comment: Download [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/) and add it to your website using script tags.  Then add a separate script which has the mentioned code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you loooked at the simple-navigation gem?

https://github.com/andi/simple-navigation

It has this functionality built in.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using bootstrap you can write data-toggle="dropdown" for example
Home