# add active state to button in a button group

Tags: jquery

I have a button group, and I'd like to add an active state to the button that's been selected, and then if another button is selected remove the highlight state from the prior one.

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="question-company-wide">
      <i class="fa fa-building fa-lg"></i> <%= t('.company_label') %>
   </button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="question-group-specific">
      <i class="fa fa-users fa-lg"></i> <%= t('.groups_label') %>
   </button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="question-user-specific">
      <i class="fa fa-user fa-lg"></i> <%= t('.employees_label') %>
   </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Pseudo code for CSS, maybe try :active
Example would be `.btn{ color:red; } .btn:active{color:blue;}`

Comment: Looks like you are using bootstrap, so this question should help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391272/active-buttons-with-bootstrap-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at below code snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div.btn-group button.btn").click(function(){
    $("div.btn-group").find(".activeButton").removeClass("activeButton");
    $(this).addClass("activeButton");
  });  
});
```

```css
.activeButton{
  color:blue;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="question-company-wide">
        <i class="fa fa-building fa-lg"></i> company_label
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="question-group-specific">
        <i class="fa fa-users fa-lg"></i> groups_label
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="question-user-specific">
        <i class="fa fa-user fa-lg"></i> employees_label
      </button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create an active class
***CSS***

```
.uiButton:active, .active {
    background-color:blue;
}
```

***JS***

```
$('.uiButton').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```